# Async Unit Testing - Unawaited Task Blocks Forever

Tags: c#, .net, testing, asynchronous, blocking

When running my application normally, any `async Task` method called without the `await` keyword does exactly what I want it to do. Start the method in a different thread, but continue execution (the compiler even happily warns me about this). This works as expected and without problems.

When this same code is run in a unit test, this unawaited method now blocks forever and my unit tests never fail.

I'm guessing that `async` methods were not designed to be used as such, although they seem to work quite well normally. Is there a way to make them work correctly in unit tests, or what would you recommend I use instead to execute code in the background without blocking (BackgroundWorker?). I liked the Task approach because it allows me to re-use the method in a blocking and non blocking way. I could use Task.Run() and pass in a lambda that calls the method, but that seems kind of ugly/unreadable.

Comment: `"Start the method in a different thread"` No, it will not do this.  An `async` method with no `await` is just a regular synchronous method that wraps the result in a completed task.  It starts no new thread at all.

Comment: It sounds like your use of `async` is highly unorthodox. Could you post a code sample?

Comment: @StephenCleary Seems like an issue with the testing framework, not the async code.  If it does a blocking wait on a top level task that is returned it would obviously deadlock if there is a `SynchronizationContext`.  The issue is that the testing framework needs to have a message pump at the top level, not a blocking wait.

Comment: @Servy: When I read the op's question, it sounds like he's unit testing a method that calls an `async Task` method without `await`ing the returned task. But there's no way to tell for sure since there's no code.

Comment: You are correct Stephen. The method is called without awaiting the Task.